# Tags [webflow-js] and [webflow-css] should be merged to [webflow]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Tags [webflow-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webflow-js) and [webflow-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webflow-css) should be merged to [webflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webflow).

Questions asked in both tags are about custom code modifications/add-ons to the [website builder](https://webflow.com), and both tags would be used together most of the time. Simplifying both tags to [webflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webflow) would make much more sense as it is for the platform Webflow.

If a question is about [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and/or [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), they should be additionally be tagged as such instead. Currently, [webflow-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webflow-js) is being misused in place of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) as you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webflow-js, resulting in these questions falling off the grid.

This will also prevent duplicate tag wiki and info content regarding the Webflow tool.